# Using NSComboboxCell with NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode5

I'm struggling to get a `NSComboboxCell` to display the options I'm expecting when loading from a `NSArray`.

```
- (IBAction)addProjector:(id)sender {

Projector *p = [[Projector alloc]init];
[p setIpAddress:[_ipAddressTextField stringValue]];
NSComboBoxCell *n = [[NSComboBoxCell alloc]init];
[n addItemsWithObjectValues:wuAvailable];
[p setGType:n];

[_list addObject:p];

[_tableView reloadData];

}
```

`wuAvailable` is an `NSArray` of `NSStrings`. When the App's loaded I'm not seeing my strings as options just get "Field" an no other options. Image below shows the problem.

Any help would be gratefully recieved.

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you be creating the `NSComboBoxCell` via the table view's delegate methods?

Comment: We’d have to see what “setGType:” does.

Comment: Thanks for the Comments @trojanfoe - I've not implemented the `NSTableViewDelegate` Maybe thats my problem? I thought you could add data manually using NSComboboxCell methods like `addItemsWithObjetValues:`

Comment: @WilShipley `setGType:` is just the setter for an `@property` in my projector class containing `NSComboBoxCell` Declaration looks like this: `@property NSComboBoxCell *GType;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you’ve done something magic to make the cell ’n’ you create appear in the tableView, it’s not going to. So, it doesn’t matter what array you assign it.

If you’ve already set up the tableView with the tableColumn that has an NSComboBoxCell in it, then you can modify that cell in your code by getting the ‘tableColumn.dataCell’ and setting properties on it.

You can get the tableColumn by its identifier from the tableView—your controller should have an IBOutlet onto the tableView.